# Немогу избавится от пустого option (Angular)

Tags: angularjs, html-select

Получаю данные из БД, массив объектов, в объекте есть только `name`,
вывожу его в селекте, и он мне первый пустой `option` создает, никак не могу
его убрать.

Помогите советом, как это корректно сделать?

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" 
    ng-model="newp.category" required 
    ng-options="item._id as item.name for item in categorys">
</select>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в БД не может быть объект с пустым name?

Comment: Нет, там по моделе (mongoose) require: true (тоесть неможет быть пустым name), да и смотрел уже в саму базу...

Answer (score 3):

Проблема в `ng-model="newp.category"`, если значение *undefined* или, возможно, значение отсутствующее в списке, то ангуляр добавит пустой элемент.

Для решения нужно инициализировать данное поле одним из элементов, например:

```
newp.category = categorys[0]._id
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.categorys = [
    {name: 'name_1', _id: 'id-1'},
    {name: 'name_2', _id: 'id-2'},
    {name: 'name_3', _id: 'id-3'},
    {name: 'name_4', _id: 'id-4'},
    {name: 'name_5', _id: 'id-5'}
  ];
  $scope.newp = {
    category2 :$scope.categorys[0]._id
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-model="newp.category1" required ng-options="item._id as item.name for item in categorys">
</select>
  <select class="form-control" id="category" ng-model="newp.category2" required ng-options="item._id as item.name for item in categorys">
</select>
</div>
```